# Vertically center report footer in remaining space on page

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to vertically center my report footer in the leftover space at the end of the page? The size of this leftover section depends on number of data rows.

[image]

Comment: can you make the data row number fix? Like 20 record per page

Comment: yes, it can 18 records per page

Comment: btw to answer your question, try ticking relative position on your report footer section.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to vertically center things in Crystal. Frustrating as it may be, there's no Vertical Alignment property on most things, and the Size/Position of things is static except when other objects push them around to make room for themselves.

*However* there is a ridiculously silly hack you can do to make this work.

Write a formula, let's call it `SillySpaceFormula`, that uses a loop to generate a certain number of return characters. Based on the number of records on this page, `SillySpaceFormula` will grow or shrink inversely. Set `Silly`'s font size to be half the size of your details section. Then place this formula in a section above the orange-outlined box and set "Can Grow" to `True`.

If you do this *just* right, `SillySpaceFormula` will grow by one line when a record is removed and shrink by one line when a record is added. Because the formula field Can Grow, the orange box in your screenshots will be moved up and down automatically.